# Checking when text changes to specific text with Selenium. Custom condition not being called

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a script to play an online game and I need it to know when it is between rounds.

In my main script I have

```
import custom_conditions

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

waiting_for_next_game = wait.until(custom_conditions.wait_for_text_to_be(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, "message-text"), "Wait for the next round"))
```

In my `custom_conditions.py`  I have

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class wait_for_text_to_be(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, text_):
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text_

    def __call__(self, driver):
        print('checking!')
        element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text
        return element_text == self.text
```

That print statement never logs so I conclude that the condition is never called. It always times out and throws `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`.
The text I am trying to target is `<span class="message-text">Wait for the next round</span>` and it changes dynamically depending on the game state.

I have also tried using

```
wait.until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "message-text"), "Wait for the next round"))
)
```

and the similar `text_to_be_present_in_element_value`.

I've also tried using `(By.CSS_SELECTOR,  "span.message-text")`

Can anyone see where I am going wrong please?

Comment: Check if there are any classes with the same named. That text to be present seems right.

Comment: I can confirm that there is only this one item with that class on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. The only change I made is replace the find_element method call. That is because I avoid calling private methods.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome  
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class WaitForTextToBe:

    def __init__(self, locator: tuple, text: str) -> None:
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self, driver: Chrome) -> None:
        print("checking...")
        element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)
        return self.text in element.text


driver = Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66725562/checking-when-text-changes-to-specific-text-with-selenium-custom-condition-not")
output = wait.until(WaitForTextToBe((By.ID, "question-header"), "Checking when text changes to specific text with Selenium. Custom condition not being called"))
print(output)

driver.quit()
```

**Output**

```
checking...
True
```

Comment: I've applied your change regarding the `find_element` call. The `custom_method` is now being called and I'm seeing "checking!" in the console many times. Thank you. However, it still times out though the text it is "listening" for changed. 
There is only this one item with that class on the page.

Comment: This makes it work, `element_text = driver.find_element(*self.locator).get_attribute('textContent')` I logged the `element_text.text` and it just stringified the Selenium object instance. Of course it wasn't matching! 
Thanks for your help. ;)